# Use many has_one relation on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a model match like this:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match, foreign_key: 'parent'
  belongs_to :match, foreign_key: 'child_left'
  belongs_to :match, foreign_key: 'child_right'
end
```

Many match represent a tree.

I would like set the foreign key to use Match.first.child_left return me the object match and not just an integer who represents is id.

Better, can I use in this case the has_one relation? because it use each the model match but with a different foreign_key.

Even better, can I be sure than when I put a child_left in a match it will set the parent attribute on the child match with the db or should I do it with ruby?

Comment: I found this but i don't succeed to make it work in my scenario: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Match'
  belongs_to :child_left, class_name: 'Match'
  belongs_to :child_right, class_name: 'Match'
end
```

Your `matches` table should have integer fields `parent_id`, `child_left_id`, `child_right_id`. You should be able to use it like this:

```
Match.first.child_left
```